# programmatically creating a Moose class at run time

Tags: perl, moose

I've been playing around with this code:

```
package Foo;
use Moose;

package main;

my $PACKAGE = "Foo";
{
  no strict 'refs';
  my $has = *{"${PACKAGE}::has"}{CODE};
  my $with = *{"${PACKAGE}::with"}{CODE};

  # Add a instance member to class $PACKAGE

  $has->("bar", is => "rw", required => 1);

  # Add a role to class $PACKAGE

  $with->("some::role");
}

# Create an instance of $PACKAGE:

$PACKAGE->new(); # error: attribute 'bar' is required means we were successful
```

This allows me to create a Moose class at run-time, i.e. add instance members to a class, add roles, etc.

My question is: how can I import Moose into package `$PACKAGE`?

I know I can do this with eval: `eval "package $PACKAGE; use Moose";` but I'm wondering if there is a solution along the lines of `Moose->import(... $PACKAGE ...)`.

i.e., a way without using `eval`. Or is there a completely different way of creating and modifying Moose classes at run time?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You probably want to take a look at [Moose::Meta::Class](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Moose/lib/Moose/Meta/Class.pm) and its `create` method:

```
my $class = Moose::Meta::Class->create('Foo',
  attributes => [attr => Moose::Meta::Attribute->new(is => 'ro'), ...],
  roles => [...],
  methods => {...},
  superclasses => [...],
);

# Edit: Adding an attribute and method modifiers:
$class->add_attribute(otherattr => (is => 'ro'));
$class->add_around_method_modifier(methodname => sub { ... });
```

`Moose::Meta::Class` is a subclass of [Class::MOP::Class](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Moose/lib/Class/MOP/Class.pm), so you might want to peek into that one as well. With the above, you can specify roles, superclasses, attributes and methods, or you can first create and then add them via the MOP; whatever fits best.

For the attributes you'll want the Moose kind, which means [Moose::Meta::Attribute](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Moose/lib/Moose/Meta/Attribute.pm) objects. The constructor to that object is basically the same as using `has`.

Comment: I saw that and rejected it. It requires a lot more work. Instead of just calling `has`, `with`, etc, you're suggesting that the user reimplements them in his code. It also doesn't provide `around` and the like.

Comment: Sure it provides it: `$meta->add_around_method_modifier(foo => sub { ... })`. The `has`, `with`, etc. functions are sugar exports just calling methods on the MOP. Sugar is awesome for declarations, but depending on it being available or hijacking it doesn't seem like a good idea to me. The methods in the MOP are what's documented and clearly supported.

Comment: Additionally: `superclasses` takes what `extends` would take, `roles` would take what `with` takes, `add_attribute` on the meta class takes the same arguments as `has`. And as soon as you want to be able to declare methods you're either back to manipulating the symbol table directly or using the MOP (hopefully the latter).

Answer (score 4):

You may want to use Class::MOP, see for example https://metacpan.org/module/Moose::Manual::MOP#ALTERING-CLASSES-WITH-THE-MOP
or
https://metacpan.org/module/Class::MOP::Class#SYNOPSIS

Comment: Moose uses MOP, but they're Moose isn't MOP. MOP doesn't know anything by roles, for starers, and the OP specifically asked how to support roles.

Comment: @ikegami A MOP is simply a Meta Object Protocol. Moose::Meta::* *is* a MOP and understands Roles. Class::MOP is another MOP (that Moose's MOP extends) that tries to reflect the implicit MOP built into Perl5, with some extensions (attributes).

Comment: @perigrin, I didn't say "a MOP", I said "MOP", as in "Class::MOP". tadzik recommended Class::MOP, and I pointed out it doesn't support roles. You didn't say anything I didn't know.

Answer (score -5):

Call `extends`, `with`, `has`, `before`, `after`, `around`, `override` and `augment` in the Moose package instead of the ones exported by Moose, and pass the `meta` object of the class you are creating as an additional first argument.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw( say );

use Moose qw( );

{ # Create MyClass on the fly.
   my $meta = Moose->init_meta( for_class => 'MyClass' );

   # Moose::with( $meta, 'MyRole' );

   Moose::has( $meta, foo => (
      is => 'ro',
   ));
}

say MyClass->new( foo => "Foo" )->foo;  # Foo
```

Comment: Interesting that you suggest `Moose::has($meta, ...)`. What about `$meta->has(...)`? Would that work? It seems more "correct" because it dispatches based on the the type of `$meta`.

Comment: @user5402, `has` is a function in package Moose, not a method of class Moose::Meta::Class

Comment: This usage is not documented though. How `has` is implemented was changed multiple times and might do so again.

Comment: @phaylon, that's exactly why you should use my method instead of using `Moose::Meta::Class`. I actually use `has`, whereas using `Moose::Meta::Class` requires recreating everything `has` does, which is not documented and subject to change.

Comment: @ikegami: You got that the wrong way around. `Class::MOP::Class`/`Moose::Meta::Class` & Co. are documented, supported and under control of the deprecation policy. The `has` sugar that is set up *in your class* when you import Moose are part of the public API as well. You are accessing `Moose::has` which is an internal callback. It's *not* the same as the `has` you use when declaring a class, that's why they take different parameters. Or can you point me to where `Moose::has($meta, $name, %args)` is documented as good practice in the Moose documentation?

Comment: @ikegami: No, that's not true at all. The supported interface is the methods in Moose::Meta::Class. `has` and such are just a convenient sugar layer, but they don't do anything other than pass the arguments through to the proper methods on the meta layer (read the source to Moose.pm, it's pretty easy). The meta layer is documented and tested, and will not change without a proper deprecation cycle. The implementation of the sugar in Moose.pm has no such guarantees - as mentioned, it has changed several times in the past, and may do so again without warning.

Comment: @Jesse Luehrs, I suggest you look at your own code. `has` does more than "they don't do anything other than pass the arguments through to the proper methods on the meta layer". `definition_context => Moose::Util::_caller_info()`, for example.

Comment: @Jesse Luehrs, "The implementation of the sugar in Moose.pm has no such guarantees". EXACTLY! That's why I use the sugar instead of copying its guts (i.e. using Moose::Meta::Class).

Comment: @ikegami: Look again, the thing in Moose.pm is not what you get setup in your class. You are advising someone to use an unsupported, undocumented interface instead of the documented, stable one. "The implementation of the sugar in Moose.pm has no such guarantees" means the thing you're calling is not supported, and might change without warning. The methods Jesse and I proposed are stable. Once more: Calling `has` the way you do is `not supported`. Please show me where it's documented or stop claiming otherwise, even after a member of the core told you differently.

Comment: @ikegami: `Moose::has` and `YourClass::has` are different things. `YourClass::has` is documented and tested and safe to use, `Moose::has` could change at any time. It originally didn't even exist (and was generated at `import` time), and more recently took `$caller` rather than `$meta` as its first argument. This could change again at any time, and if it does, your code *will* break. Code using the documented API in Moose::Meta::Class will not.

Comment: @Jesse Luerhs, I know they are different things, but you it's the safer of the two alternative given (Use `Moose::has` or copy `Moose::has`).

Comment: @phaylon, I'm not advising someone to use an unsupported, undocumented interface, I'm saying they have no choice but to do so. My approach relies the *least* on undocumented features.

Comment: @phaylon, @Jesse Luerhs, Before saying that using Moose::Class::Meta is safer one more time, give an example usage of Moose::Class::Meta (one attribute sufficient) that does the same as `has`. Remember, it has to do everything `has` does. Your have provided absolutely no basis for your argument that Moose::Class::Meta is safer, where as I actually looked at `has`.

Comment: According to your argument, you should be able to do with at without looking at `has`, but Jesse himself was already mistaken about what `has` does. (He said "they don't do anything other than pass the arguments through to the proper methods on the meta layer".)

Comment: I'm not mistaken, `definition_context` is solely for debugging information, and it isn't relevant or possible to figure out in an automated way if you're creating classes dynamically. You're free to pass it yourself, with values that make sense, but calling Moose::has is going to end up with nonsense values in there *anyway*. Your example is invalid. I'm not just making things up here, I'm the maintainer of Moose, and I know the codebase very well. Using Moose::Meta::Class *is* safer.

Comment: @Jesse Luerhrs, You're saying the contents of `init_meta`, `has`, etc are less likely to change than the parameters they take, and that makes no sense

Comment: @Jesse Luerhrs, What's the appropriate alternative to `$meta->_add_meta_method($meta_name)`? Is  `$meta->superclasses($base_class) unless $meta->superclasses();` a no-op? Why are you saying that I should know this?